# Create Config-Map from my properties file, using k8s client

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am trying to create a config-map form a file, using k8s client.

content of application.properties, I have this file as File java object.

```
propertyOne="Something_One"
propertyTwo="Something_Two"
```

now I have no clue, how I should create a config-map.
**ConfigMapBuilder** has few options for **.withData()** or **.addToData()** but these consumes only **Map<String, String>**

My goal is to create this config-map, and assign this to a Pod using **EnvFromSourceBuilder**, by using config-map name and assigning that to my **ContainerBuilder**, and only blocker is creating Config-Map.

Can anyone please help me out, thanks in advance :)

Comment: this feature is under implementation, https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/4712/files#diff-b95b04f298d96edfaaefd6c00f835dba2dd308eee090ba0c8ea35c22610b2851R80

so any work around till then?